# Python using a var to compare a value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

this has been puzzling me for days and I can't find a resolution anywhere. Here is my code:

```
dict = {"ip1":{'port':29500, 'count':0},
        "ip2":{'port':29501, 'count':0},
        "ip3":{'port':29502, 'count':0},
        "ip4":{'port':29503, 'count':0}}

def myFunction():
    with  settings(warn_only=True):
       data = run('/usr/local/cbin/port_check.sh').splitlines()
       data2 = run('/usr/local/cbin/port_check.sh')
    filter(None, data)
    filtered = filter(lambda x: not re.match(r'^\s*$', x), data) 
    if filtered[-1] != "text string":
       print "Bazzinga! text string found."
       m = map((lambda x: re.search("(\d\d\d\d\d)", x)), filtered)
       for y in m:
           if y is not None:
              z = y.group(1)
              z.rstrip('\r\n')
              for key, val in dict.iteritems():
                  print "-"+z+"-"
                  if dict[key]["port"] == z:
                  dict[key]["count"]+=1
                  print key, "=>", dict[key]["port"], dict[key]["count"]
```

So problem is when I use the var z in (if dict[key]["port"] == z) It does not work even though I've rigged it to match. I can print z but the comparison (==) doesn't work. If I replace z with 29500 then the if statement works.

Comment: Please introduce the problem. Don't expect people to decipher the semantics of your uncommented code.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I'm using the fabric API to run commands on remote machines. That is why you see with  ... settings(warn_only=True):
       data = run('/usr/local/cbin/port_check.sh').splitlines()
       data2 = run('/usr/local/cbin/port_check.sh')

Comment: Have you tried indenting the code underneath `if dict[key]["port"] == z:`? Or negating the if-statement if you are intending to have an empty if-statment

Comment: `filter(None, data)` does not alter data, it returns the result of filtering which you discard. Calling a variable `dict` shadows the built-in class `dict`; usually a bad idea. Indentation after the problematic `if` is weird. In the meantime, `collections.Counter` may be of interest for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like `z` is a string, which will not compare equal to an integer. Use `int(z)` in the comparison. Or compare string representations:

```
if str(dict[key]["port"]) == z:
```

which has the advantage that it will not raise a `ValueError` if the string `z` happens to contain something that cannot be turned into an integer.